# Запятые при обособлении деепричастного оборота

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли здесь обособлять деепричастный оборот?

С учетом сказанного и отталкиваясь от определения сущности войны по К. Клаузевицу можно дать определение энергетической войны как противоборства воли социальных субъектов с целью захвата источников энергии, средств их доставки и рынков сбыта.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"С учетом сказанного и отталкиваясь от определения сущности войны по К. Клаузевицу,  можно дать определение энергетической войны как противоборства воли социальных субъектов с целью захвата источников энергии, средств их доставки и рынков сбыта".

Деепричастный оборот однороден по отношению к обстоятельству "с учетом сказанного", одиночный союз И, обособляется вся конструкция.

Дополнение

Не следует применять правила формально. Действительно, мы не обособляем деепричастный оборот в следующем случае: "Он вдруг и не объясняя причины расхохотался совершенно искренне". Но здесь деепричастный оборот выступает в роли наречия, то есть является обстоятельством образа действия. В нашем же случае это аналог СПП, значение действия.

Answer (score 0):

Помнится, у Розенталя сказано, что не обособляется деепричастный оборот, употребляющийся в качестве однородного члена с необособленным обстоятельством. Пример: Остановив Власову, он одним дыханием и не ожидая ответов закидал ее трескучими и глухими словами (М.Г.). По-моему, [[@Alenka](/users/4012/alenka)](/users/4012/alenka), здесь именно такой случай, так что Вы поторопились принимать ответ.